# Read a JSON list in list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have a  json like this  :

```
{
   "Project 
      [id=1, dateDebut=2017-01-13, dateFin=2017-01-18, description=qsd, sponsor=qsd ]"
    :
 [
  {"id":1,"title":"qsd ","description":"qsdqsd","dateFin":"2017-01-26"},
  {"id":2,"title":"sss ","description":"sss","dateFin":"2017-01-26"}
 ]
}
```

originated from : `return new ObjectMapper.write(Map<Project,List<Task>> projectTasks = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>()) ;`

**EDIT** : this is the real response :

```
{"Project [id=1, name=qsdsqd, type=null, done=false, dateDebut=2017-01-13, dateFin=2017-01-18, description=qsd, sponsor=qsd, client=qsd, showable=true]":
[{"id":1,"title":"qsd ","description":"qsdqsd","dateFin":"2017-01-26","dateDebut":"2017-01-14","period":null,"done":false,"status":"Actif","priority":"Normal"},
{"id":2,"title":"task 2 ","description":"qsdqsd","dateFin":"2017-01-26","dateDebut":"2017-01-14","period":null,"done":false,"status":"Actif","priority":"Normal"}]}
```

How can I read the list of tasks in the client side ?

Comment: That is not valid JSON

Comment: That's the server response which is a return from `ObjectMapper`

Comment: Why the minus?? Before you put it you should've explained

Comment: @RamblinRose did you just assume its type?

Comment: I guess people might have voted this down assuming this is not a valid JOSN, although it is! (confirmed at http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: Yes it's! They think they know everything, even my server know better than them

Comment: @AnuragSinha it's only valid with some additional editing.

Comment: @AnuragSinha, it's invalid with the newline in the first key, which I assume is a copy/paste error. I down-voted this because it's unclear and shows a lack of effort. If this is the response from a server call, then this is already available to the client...

Comment: Well I copy pasted then I modified it to look comprehensive to the reader, can't a man mistype?

Comment: @Brian not sure what you mean by "assume its type"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your JSON is not valid. Are you sure that is a line break between the word `Project` and `[id...]`. A valid JSON would be:

```
{
   "Project [id=1, dateDebut=2017-01-13, dateFin=2017-01-18, description=qsd, sponsor=qsd, ]":
 [
  {"id":1,"title":"qsd ","description":"qsdqsd","dateFin":"2017-01-26"},
  {"id":2,"title":"sss ","description":"sss","dateFin":"2017-01-26"}
 ]
}
```

You **can** have object key names like that. But i'ts not very friendly to retrieve data.

If you cannot change your data schema (or just don't want), you can iterate over the Object with the

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach ( (key) => {
   console.log('key: ' + key);
   console.log('value: ' + obj[key]);

   /* you can iterate over your value (tasks) here */
   obj[key].forEach( (task) => {
      console.log('task1: ', task);
   });

});  //where obj is your json
```

Or you can access the first object property with:

```
obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]]; //where obj is your json
```

**EDIT** As pointed by  @André Dion, `forEach`is best suited to iteration, not `map`. And we're assuming your response is already parsed from the server (by yourself or by a lib like jquery). If not, you should do a `JSON.parse(response);` to retrieve the object.

Comment: Don't use `Array#map` to iterate, that's `Array#forEach`'s job. This also assumes an Object, not JSON. You would need to call `JSON.parse` on the response first.

Comment: @AndréDion [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) return an Array. Yes, I'm assuming it's an already parsed object.

Comment: I'm aware of how `Object.keys` works. My points still stand: don't iterate with `map` and if `obj` represents the server response, you'd need `var obj = JSON.parse(response)` first.

Comment: I get it. You're right. I am very used with map. Will edit.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:
Assume above response in stored in var response.

```
for(var project in response) { // this will get every project
    for(var i=0; i<project.length; i++) { // this will iterate over the array for each project which are your tasks.
         console.log("task" + project[i]);
         console.log(project[i]["id"]); // access each tasks id, similar for other attributes
    }
}
```